# Mail Routing using pipe in Exim

Tags: php, linux, centos, pipe, exim

I was looking for sending email to multiple destinations i.e One to the user specified email address and other to a php script. Surfing over the web, I concluded that I have to use pipe in routers and transfer configurations of my mailing agent i.e Exim in my case. I tried but failed to embed pipe transfer in my Exim configurations. Server results in failing pipe transfer. Need help in getting this issue fixed.
I modified my exim.cnf file as:

```
############ ROUTERS
system_aliases:
driver = accept 
domains = **.**.**.**(my Domain) 
transport = use_pipe

############ TRANSPORT
use_pipe:
debug_print = "Using Pipe Transport"
driver = pipe
command = /etc/script.php
return_path_add
delivery_date_add
envelope_to_add
return_output
```

where script.php is the second destination where I want to send the file.
Here are the Logs:

```
 3402   uid=3000 gid=3000 pid=3402
 3402   auxiliary group list: 3000
 3402   home=NULL current=/
 3402 set_process_info:  3402 delivering 1ZTPOU-0000sn-JB to abc using use_pipe
 3402 Using Pipe Transport
 3402 use_pipe transport entered
 3402 direct command:
 3402   argv[0] = /etc/testScript.php
 3402 direct command after expansion:
 3402   argv[0] = /etc/testScript.php
 3402 Writing message to pipe
 3402 writing data block fd=10 size=44 timeout=3600
 3402 writing data block fd=10 size=2048 timeout=3600
 3402 writing data block fd=10 size=1 timeout=3600
 3404 set_process_info:  3404 reading output from |/etc/testScript.php
 3402 use_pipe transport yielded 2
 3402 search_tidyup called
 3399 use_pipe transport returned FAIL for abc@myDomain
 3399 post-process abc@myDomain (2)
 3399 LOG: MAIN
 3399   ** abc@myDomain R=system_aliases T=use_pipe: Child process of use_pipe transport returned 127 (could mean unable to exec or command does not exist) from command: /etc/testScript.php
```

*testScript is present at the exact location specified in logs.

Comment: Could you include EXACT error messages generated in the log files?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip logs are included. Have a look.

Comment: 1) check permissions of the script file: `ls -l /etc/testScript.php` . Can user with uid 3000 execute it? 2) check validity of first line of the script `#!...` . Can user  with uid 3000 execute the program? http://linux.die.net/man/1/php

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I have checked. There seems not any issue either with the permissions of file or user ownership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In routers section I wrote my own custom router that will deliver email to my desired php script. In transport section wrote my own custom transport that will ensure delivery to the desired script using curl. Kept the `system_aliases` section in Routers configuration as it is but changed driver from `accept` to `redirect`.Wrote the following configurations in my `/etc/exim.cnf` file:

```
############ROUTERS
runscript:
        driver = accept
        transport = run_script
        unseen
        no_expn
        no_verify
############TRANSPORT
run_script:
     debug_print = "T: run_script for $local_part@$domain"
     driver = pipe
     command = /home/bin/curl http://my.domain.com/mailTest.php --data-urlencode $original_local_part@$original_domain
```

mailTest.php was my php script